# When to choose @RequestParam over @PathVariable and vice-versa?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I know what `@RequestParam` does and what `@PathVariable` does on an individual note but my question is when building a URL, when should I go for `@RequestParam` and when for `@PathVariable`?  What are the pros and and cons of using both these annotations?

I did go through this link [When to go for @RequestParam and @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339002/when-to-go-for-requestparam-and-pathvariable) but did not get a satisfactory answer anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

Comment: @mnwsmit No, not duplicate. There it tells what both these annotations are but doesnt weigh each against the other. I want a comparison plus I want to know the scenarios where each of them are better to use.

Comment: In that case the question is probably too broad for stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@PathVariable` identifies the pattern that is used in the URI for the incoming request.

Query args (`@RequestParam`) are used on querying/searching resources exclusively. They contain data that affects the query.

Here are [some tips](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) for creating good URLs.

Answer (score 3):

It makes more sense to use `@Pathvariable` to give the user an idea of what the page means.
`twitter.com/{userid}`
`@RequestParams`can be used to get info as parameter, like `twitter.com?search=%23yolo`
 `@Pathvariable` will help the user navigate or directly move to certain views/pages.

Answer (score 0):

**@PathVariable:**

When u need to pass parameters along with the url to get the data. In Spring MVC, u can customize the URL in order to get data. For this purpose @PathVariable annotation is used in Spring framework. @PathVariable is used to obtain some placeholder from the uri (Spring call it an URI Template).

**@RequestParam:**

Is used to obtain an request parameter. @RequestParam binds a request parameter to a parameter in your method.