# @PathVariable vs @RequestParam to retrieve an entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http

I know the difference between `@PathVariable` and `@RequestParam`, that's not the point.

I have also read some articles but I still don't understand when to use one or the other in a simple case.

For a REST API, let's say I have a `User` entity with  `id` and `username` (both are unique).

Now I want to get a user by username.

I have 2 options :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/users/{username}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUser(@PathVariable String username){
    //Get user
}
```

or

```
@GetMapping(path = "/users}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUser(@RequestParam String username){
    //Get user
}
```

Which one do I have to use (@RequestParam is not mandatory in the code, I placed it just to be clearer) ?

Thanks

Comment: It's entirely up to you but a typical REST API will use IDs in the path so I would go for option #2 personally (without the trailing `/` on `/users/`), eg `/users?username=whatever`

Comment: It is a design choice. if you want to access the URL like this "/users/john" you use path variable, but with request param, "/users?username=john".  possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878684/when-to-choose-requestparam-over-pathvariable-and-vice-versa

Comment: Thanks, I edited for the `/`

Comment: I saw the possible duplicated question but I don't really have my answer, for me it's not clear...

Comment: The issue with mixing path variables is being able to tell the difference between `/users/{username}` and `/users/{id}`. You can use a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527321/what-is-the-meaning-of-id-in-a-spring-mvc-requestmapping-handler-method) in the request mapping but that really depends on the data type of your `id`

Comment: Note: It's best, when practical, to return `ResponseEntity<ActualResultType>` (or just return the result type and dispense with the `ResponseEntity` unless you need to set headers).

Comment: Thanks for that. The reason is that at the beginning it asked me for a type and I saw somewhere `<Object>`. As it works, I left like that :-). But totally agree, it's ok with the returned type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path part of a URL identifies a *resource*, and a query string represents a *query*. While a query can certainly return exactly one item, a collection-resource URL (`/users`) should return an *array* of items (from zero to infinity), while a record-resource URL (`/users/123`) should return *exactly one item* (and this is the URL that should handle DELETE/PUT requests).

If the `username` is actually the canonical ID for the user, it should be a path variable; if there is a different canonical ID (such as a UUID), but you're searching by username, then use a query parameter but return a collection of zero or one results. (You can use `params=username` in the request mapping to only match the controller when that query parameter is present.)

Comment: Ok, so maybe if I have the id and I want to know for exemple the email, let's go with path variable. If I want to look for a user with a username, let's go with param. Would it be a solution?

Comment: @Manta Presuming that the username is different from the ID (which is a good practice, so that you can change the username), then that's exactly how to do it. You'll usually want to limit the request mapping with `params` in that case.

Comment: Always use `id` even if `username` is unique, I think it's better in term of performance, memory usage, editable capabilities, joining, etc...Finally I understood, thanks for all.